# Targeting .net framework 3.5 and 4.0 with mixed mode assembly

Tags: .net, mixed-mode

i have a mixed mode assembly that targets .net 3.5 using the vc 9.0 runtime. i do wan't to support .net 4.0 yet still remain compatible to the old framework as well (the library should work for 4.0 and for 3.5 processes).

if i update to .net 4.0 i have to use the vc 10.0 runtime. however from this runtime i can't target an old .net framework anymore.

at the moment i don't see a way how to support older .net frameworks from a mixed mode assembly using the vc 10 runtime. does anyone know of a way how to accomplish this?

kind regards

Comment: Huh?  Is this just a deployment problem?

Comment: no, it's a compile/link problem. the problem is that i can't build mixed mode assemblies using the vc10 runtime against any .net framework before 4.0. yet i have to, because my app should support both .net 3.5 and .net 4.0 apps.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535253/not-possible-to-change-net-target-for-mixed-mode-projects)

Using Visual Studio 2010, basically you have to :

1. Manually edit the project file to add `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.
2. Use the v90 Platform Toolset.